# How to hide my updates from a particular person in Facebook

Tags: facebook

I want to hide my updates, which include my likes, posting comments etc. from a particular person (who is in my friend list). How can achieve this?

Comment: There are friend groups which you can set permissions/visibility for. It's an extra step for each new person you friend, since you will want to have a "limited" group and a normal group that you add each person to, but you can control a lot that way. I'll explore how my groups work this evening in case the process is buried like facebook sometimes does.

Answer (score 3):

Add that person who is in your friend list to your 'Restricted list'.

[image: Adding a friend to the 'Restricted list']

> #### What happens when I add someone to the Restricted list?
>
> When you add someone to your Restricted list, they'll only be able to see your [Public content](https://www.facebook.com/help/www/203805466323736) or posts that you tag them in. So if you put your boss on your Restricted list, post a photo and choose Friends as the audience, your boss (and anyone else on Restricted) won’t see that photo. However, if you add a tag of your boss to the photo, we’ll let them know they’re in it and they’ll be able to see the photo. If someone else tries to tag your boss in one of your photos, you’ll get to approve this tag from your [pending posts](https://www.facebook.com/help/www/168229546579373).

<sup>Source: [‘*What happens when I add someone to the Restricted list?*’ Facebook Help article](https://www.facebook.com/help/www/206571136073851)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you can do is **block** someone. You cannot hide all your activity from a specific person. Therefore you are going to want to unfriend them, or even better block them.

Go to *Account Settings*, and then the *Blocking* tab and add their name into it.

[image: blocking user - image example]

Comment: Blocking the person is like blowing up the building you just want to close the door of. Doing so will unfriend the person in both directions, and make them unable to see anything about you at all, ever. It's not "the only way" to accomplish this. It works, but it's a few steps further than what the asker seems to be trying to accomplish.

Comment: @phantom42 it is a safe way to prevent someone from seeing anything about you.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way to do this.

I have a specific person that I have set to restricted, yet whenever I comment on a specific third party's post, she invariably follows me to leave a comment as well.  This third party is a friend of mine but not listed as a mutual friend.

Furthermore, when I go to view my timeline "as" the restricted person in question, it pops up a notification saying:  "Remember: Things you hide from your timeline still appear in news feed, search and other places on Facebook."

Finally, when I go to the Activity Log to adjust privacy settings for comments, it does not allow me to set the privacy for those comments, and the drop down arrow to the right only offers the option to Delete the entire comment.

Answer (score -1):

What you can do is to be very careful about liking or commenting anywhere you don't want that person to see. If you comment on a public post that'll definitely appear on that person's newsfeed. To avoid this, only like or comment to those posts which are secured with the privacy "friends" and make sure that person have no friendship with your entire facebook friendlist. If that person is important enough and your freedom is ,too ,you have to take these hassle. Sorry for you.